# Find 10 most similar data points from 100?

Tags: scikit-learn, clustering, similarity

I am trying to solve a problem where I need to group battery cells that are most similar to each other to form a reliable battery pack. It seems like a clustering problem but I only need to find the top 10 most similar cells from 100.

Is there any way i can solve this?

Comment: What sort of data has been given to you?

Answer (score 1):

That is often called [nearest-neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search).

The most common methods require a distance metric. Given the features of battery pack, how close to each other are they?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually, i am in the process of collecting data.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention it might be solved via clustering, but given you need the top n to each other you can go as follows:

Assuming you have matrix X of nxm (n- batteries m- features/attributes of each one)

1. Define a distance metric (Euclidean, Mahalanobis, etc)
2. Calculate the distance between a battery j and all the other batteries i - j
3. Sort the top n distances from a battery

In pseudo code it will be something like this:

```
def kclosest(frame, battery_id, metric = "euclidean", top = 10):
    """
    Return the top n closest from battery id
    """
    distances = list()
    for index, row in frame.iterrows():
        d = metric(frame[frame.id == battery_id].values, row)
        distances.append(d)
    return sorted(distances)[1:top] # The closest point will always be the itself that's why we get from 1 to top
```